# Create a user friendly message mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling

What would be the best way to send a `MySQL` error message to the user.
At the moment the messages come through like this `"Error Duplicate entry 'onlineforu ltd' for key 'customer_company_name_2'"` which is ok for myself.
I would like a system that gets the error and would return a reply something like this `"onlineforu ltd already exists"`

Thanks

Comment: turn off error checking and use `echo "Failed";`

Comment: Or use a try/catch, log the error for yourself, and return a failed message back to the user. You can then also check the error message for certain strings to tailor the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments

`turn off` error checking

```
error_reporting(0);
```

and then check for your `query` failure and echo custom `error messages`

like

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowcount>0){
// do further procesing
}
else{
$error = "your custom error message";
}
```

Comment: Why do a row count when you can check for false?

Comment: Hi, my issue is that there could be many errors how can i define a message for every type of error. I do not want a standard error message for all errors.